# How do Rust async runtimes (e.g. tokio) handle channels?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I am a C programmer. I wrote a program which has a thread which does 2 things:

- handlers network interface (receive requests and send responses);
- waits for messages from other threads.

I used `epoll` in this thread. It handles network easily. However, in order to wait for messages, I have to use `pipe` to transfer message, just because the `pipe`'s fd can be handled by `epoll`.

--

Now, I am learning Rust and its async part. I find that the async runtimes (e.g. tokio):

- use `epoll` too;
- can handle both network IO and channel;
- However, I guess the channel should not be implemented by `pipe`.

So, my question is that, how do these runtimes handle channels (by `epoll`) as well as network IO? Or how do the channels wake up `epoll` when receiving messages?

In another words, where do the runtimes block at when there is no task to do? For example, in C program with `epoll`, it blocks at `epoll_wait` when no task.

I tried to read the code but there are too many encapsulation levels. It's hard to find the answer easy. So I come here.

Comment: we want to help. but stack overflow is about helping with code samples you've tried.  i would look into tokio's tcplistener possibly. you can directly work with the tcp stacks buffer and respond or read it etc.. if that's what you meant.

Comment: Waking up epoll is easy: you just need a file descriptor that your epoll always monitors. For example eventfd or even a pipe. I don't know which one Tokio uses but it has to do something like this.

Comment: That being said it is also possible that network layer is separated from task scheduler and runs on separate thread. And so channels run independently of epoll. I really don't know these implementation details.

Comment: I guess channels do not use eventfd or pipe, because of the performance, I guess again.

Comment: Most of the time they don't need to wake-up `epoll` because the channel sender will be woken-up from another task that's already running from the same thread, so it'll just check the condition before calling `epoll_wait` again. When calling from another thread, I guess they use a pipe or [`eventfd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) like everyone else.

Comment: Since tokio can run single thread by `new_current_thread()`, the separate thread may not be right.

Comment: @BingzhengWu I'm not saying each channel has its own eventfd/pipe. That's unlikely. I'm saying that each epoll instance has an additional, single eventfd/pipe attached for the purpose of waking it up. That's how I would do it anyway.

Comment: And then communication between threads can be done by thread safe objects, and you only need to wake up epoll, so that the thread can pick up other, nonio tasks. I think that's how libuv works, not sure about tokio though.

Comment: @freakish I see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: I use `strace` to check tokio, and yes, it uses `epoll` and `eventfd`. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

`tokio` does call `epoll_wait()`. It is deep inside the code, [inside the low-level dependency `mio`](https://github.com/tokio-rs/mio/blob/200f66202c4cf1414960569660c1449993d9c71a/src/sys/unix/selector/epoll.rs#L104-L109), but it is there.

However, `tokio` parks in `epoll_wait()` (waiting without a timeout) only after handling all pending tasks. When you send data in a channel, the channel implementation wakes the receiver's [`Waker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/task/struct.Waker.html), and this puts the receiver task on the pending queue (if it is not already there). So tokio will poll it before parking.

Comment: Thanks. I think what you said is about tasks (who share the channel) are in same thread. So what about the tasks in different threads? If a task sends message to a channel, and the receiver task is in another thread, then how does the sender wake up the receiver's thread who parks in `epoll_wait()`? Does it use `eventfd`?

Comment: @BingzhengWu On Linux, yes, it uses eventfd. The implementation is documented at [mio::Waker](https://docs.rs/mio/latest/mio/struct.Waker.html#implementation-notes).